# What does "%%%ds" mean in a c program formatting text?

Tags: c, printf, conversion-specifier

This c code I wrote below to centre text in strings works.
I cannot find an explanation of what "%%%ds" in the program means and how it works.
There is d for int and s for string but the three percentage symbols is obscure to me.
What does "%%%ds" mean and how does it work?

```
/************************************************
formattCentre.c
example of formatting text to centre
************************************************/
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char *verse[] =
{
  "The quick brown fox",
  "Jumps over the lazy dog",
  NULL
  };

int main()
{
        char **ch_pp;

 /* centre the data */
   
        for ( ch_pp = verse; *ch_pp; ch_pp++ )
        {
            int length;
            char format[10];
            length = 40 + strlen ( *ch_pp ) / 2;  /* calculate the field length  */
            sprintf ( format, "%%%ds\n", length ); /* make a format string.       */
            printf ( format, *ch_pp );       /* print the lines*/
        }
      printf( "\n" );
}
```

Comment: Read the documentation for the [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) family. `%%` produces a single `%` in output. `%d` produces a platform `int` in output, taken from the variadic argument list. The two together produce a `%` char followed by an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this call

```
sprintf ( format, "%%%ds\n", length );
```

the string format will look like

```
"%Ns\n"
```

where N is the value of the expression length.

The two adjacent symbols `%%` are written in the string format as one symbol `%`.

From the C Standard (7.21.6.1 The fprintf function)

> 8 The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:
>
> % A % character is written. No argument is converted. The complete
> conversion specification shall be **%%**

Try this simple demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char s[2];

    sprintf( s, "%%" );

    puts( s );
}
```

Its output is

```
%
```

So the next call of printf will look like

```
printf ( "%Ns\n", *ch_pp );
```